# ASIHTTPRequest resume request after losing internet connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, asihttprequest

How to handle losing of internet connection? I'm using ASIHTTPReqeust to download file, and i want to handle when my internet connection is available and not, for resuming download. Who did something like that?  When i disable wi-fi while downloading file, ASIHTTPReqeustDelegate calls method requestFaliled:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request; How to start download after enabling internet?

P.S. I download files asynchronously ([request startAsynchronous];)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation covers this:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#resuming_interrupted_downloads

Comment: Yes, I know about this link. And i finally realized how works resuming downloads. When interned connection loses, temp file doesn't delete, to continue download I have to create new request to same url and download will continue. But I didn't find how to pause download. But thanks for reply

Comment: To pause a request I would presume you just cancel it, then create a new one when you're ready to try again.

Comment: Yes, i found it:) What aboud deleting temp file? If i want to stop request at all I need to delete temp file myself or ASIHTTPRequest can do this?

Comment: If you want to abort (rather than pause) the download you'll need to clean up the temporary file yourself I believe.

Comment: I am not able to resume the download all after have the steps said in the above link. Its starting download from beginning. @TimurMustafaev, did get the solution for the same?

Comment: @Hemang Use charlesproxy (or similar) to check what's going on - in particular check what Range: headers are being send, and whether the server is returning 206 Partial content correctly when the Range: header is sent. If you see Range: headers being sent, and don't 206 Partial content responses, the problem is on the server side.